# How to do a POST request to upload a file and data in cURL from the command line

Tags: json, curl, post, file-upload, http-post

I am trying to send a POST Request in cURL to an API while following the given requirements.

> Guidelines:
>
> - The content type for the submission should be application/json
> - The following is the structure of the body:
>
>   - Name: String
>   - PhoneNumber: String
>   - Email: String
>   - Position: String
>   - Urls: Array of objects containing the following properties
>
>     - Type: String
>     - Link: String
> - All fields are required
> - At least one URL with the "Resume" type is required
> - For resumes, we require submissions to be in PDF format
> - If your submission was successful, you will receive a HTTP 202 response

I believe I have the proper syntax for all my data I want to send in JSON but I am not sure how to upload a PDF in the same request.

Here is my syntax so far.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -
     X POST -d '{"json":{"Name":"data"}}' -d '{"json":
     {"PhoneNumber":"data"}}' -d '{"json":{"Email":"data"}}' -d '{"json":
     {"Position":"data"}}' https://example
```

When I enter this into the command line I get an 'HTTP 400 Bad Request' response when of course I am shooting for a 202 response.

I mostly program in Python and R so using cURL is new to me. Any help so I can  send this application is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing several `-d` makes the data pieces passed as parameter list delimited by `&`, i.e. `-d data1 -d data2` would result into passing `data1&data2` in the http request body.

You need to pass your entire JSON string in one go:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST
    -d '{"Name":"data", "PhoneNumber":"data", "Email":"data", "Position":"data"}'
    https://example
```

N.B. Mind the closing `"` after `"Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your comment. I am still not able to successfully send the request, but I am close. The issue is with my URL it needs to be 'an array of objects'. Do you know how to do this or should I create another question to try to solve this?

Comment: @Dre: You're welcome! I don't quite understand what you mean by URL being 'an array of objects'. Could you please clarify this and provide an example?

Comment: I was told my JSON string was pretty close, which is good, but the issue is with the array requirement from the guidelines above. I too am not sure what the "an array of objects" means but here is what I tried. `curl -g -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"Name":"data", "PhoneNumber":"data", "Email":"data@gmail.com", "Position":"data", "Url":[{"Github":"github.com/data"},{"Resume":"linkedin.com/in/data"}]}' https://envoc-apply-api.azurewebsites.net/api/apply` but I still receive an invalid request body response. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Dre: The API specifies that array field to be `Urls`, not `Url`. Mind the plural `s` in the field name.

Answer (score -1):

Try this its working!

```
        try{

            var httpclient = new HttpClient();
            Urls[] url = new Urls[]
            {
                new Urls("Resume", "https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZV0YvZyqR708s0VNkTCMigM8AvdyEhE59y")

                };
            var envocdata = new envoc_data
            {
                Name = "Prasanna",
                PhoneNumber = "data",
                Email = "prasannadata@gmail.com",
                Position = "Xamarin Developer",
                Urls = url

            };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envocdata);
            HttpContent httpcontent = new StringContent(json);
            httpcontent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var result = await httpclient.PostAsync("http://envoc-apply-api.azurewebsites.net/api/apply", httpcontent);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayAlert("", ""+ex.Message, "Ok");
        }
```